# Get pre-header from HTML using regex

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to extract the pre-header from a HTML using regex. The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>...</head>
<body dir="ltr" style="padding: 0; margin: 0"><div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">This is my preheader &mdash; </div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width: 100%">
...
</body></html>
```

This means that the pre-header is placed directly after the `<body>` start tag as a `<div>` element. Furthermore, it has the `display: none` style class. So I think it would be best to extract the first element after the `<body>` start tag, then check if it's a `<div>` with corresponding style class (otherwise no pre-header maintained) and if so, extract the text from it ignoring escapes and stuff like `&mdash;`.

I would like to implement this in JavaScript. It would help me very much to 1) know the regex to extract the first element after the `<body>` start tag and 2) extract the plain text value from the `<div>` element.

Thank you very much for assistance in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use `regex` instead of a simple `querySelector`?

Comment: Regexes are absolutely not the tool you want here. Just use native DOM functionality.